# How to use procedures with generic lists in VHDL-2008?

Tags: segmentation-fault, vhdl, procedure, generic-list

I refactored some working VHDL code to use a `procedure` with a generic list, and now it segfaults in Modelsim (2020.1).

The procedure's generic list includes a `type` and another `procedure`.

The segfault seems to be happening because a `std.textio.line` (which is an `access` type) becomes `NULL` when it is passed into the procedure indicated in the generic list.

I have provided below what I think is minimal code to reproduce the problem. Note that the seemingly irrelevant `dummy_t` type (which is mapped to `integer`) is required to reproduce the error. If I delete this dummy type (and value) then the `line` doesn't become `NULL`.

```vhdl
use std.textio.all;

package test_pkg is
    
    -- Some external procedure
    procedure p0(L : inout line; x : integer);
    
    -- Uninstantiated generic procedure
    procedure p1_generic
        generic (type dummy_t; procedure p2(L : inout line; x : dummy_t))
        parameter (L : inout line; x : dummy_t);
    
    -- Instance of generic procedure
    procedure p1 is new p1_generic
        generic map(dummy_t => integer, p2 => p0);
    
end package;

package body test_pkg is
    
    -- Some external procedure
    procedure p0(L : inout line; x : integer) is
    begin
        assert L /= NULL report "p0: L is NULL." severity Failure;
    end;
    
    -- Uninstantiated generic procedure
    procedure p1_generic
        generic (
            type dummy_t;
            procedure p2(L : inout line; x : dummy_t)
        )
        parameter (L : inout line; x : dummy_t) is
    begin
        assert L /= NULL report "p1: L is NULL." severity Failure;
        p2(L, x);
    end;

end package body;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Testbench
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
use std.textio.all;
use work.test_pkg.all;

entity testbench is
end testbench;

architecture arch of testbench is
begin
    
    process
        variable Line_v : line := new string'("Hello");
    begin
        p1(Line_v, 123);
        deallocate(Line_v);
        wait;
    end process;
    
end architecture;
```

I saved this in a file named test_pkg.vhd and simulated it as follows:

```
vlib lib
vcom -2008 -work lib test_pkg.vhd
vsim lib.testbench
run -all
```

This error is repeatable on multiple runs (`restart -f; run -all`):

```
# ** Fatal: (SIGSEGV) Bad handle or reference.
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Process: /testbench/line__54 File: test_pkg.vhd
# Fatal error in Process line__54 at test_pkg.vhd line 57
```

(This suggests L was not NULL immediately before being output from `p0`, but then it became somehow corrupted after being returned `p0` -> `p1` -> testbench).

I tried printing out `L.all` inside each procedure and I get different garbage in each case:

```
èíJ]pè%K]èð]‹Eè‹P‹
‹Eè‹P‹
```

If I recompile with `vcom -2008 -work lib test_pkg.vhd` then I get a different failure:

```
# ** Failure: p0: L is NULL.
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Process: /testbench/line__54 File: test_pkg.vhd
```

(This suggests L was not NULL immediately before being passed into `p0`, but then became NULL immediately inside that procedure).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you raised a ticket with seimens? I suspect modelsim bug

Comment: @Tricky I also suspect a bug. I'll try to figure out how to raise a ticket. In the past, I've ended up going round in circles trying to report Modelsim bugs... but I've now got a couple I need to report. Two birds with one stone.